# Count the number of rows based on the value of child array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to count the number of rows having a child array element value as true.

```
{
   _id: 1,
   name: 'test',
   items: [{'name': 'harry', valid: true}]
},
{
   _id: 2,
   name: 'walter',
   items: [{'name': 'potter', valid: false}]
},
{
   _id: 3,
   name: 'walter',
   items: [{'name': 'baby', valid: true}]
}
```

I need to get count using aggregate function.
result being,

```
count 3, valid: 2, nonValid: 1
```

Could any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "valid": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$items",
            "cond": "$$this.valid"
          }
        }
      },
    "nonValid": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$items",
            "cond": { "$not": "$$this.valid" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

You only need a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) pipeline and the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator here. The "counting arrays" is done via [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) from the matching elements of [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) where the `cond` requries a Boolean expression.

Since `valid` in the array items is already Boolean, the returned value must be `true` to be the `valid` count, or [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/) `true` to be `nonValid`

Comment: This looks promising. But what If I want to add another condition with the same filter. name is walter and item.valid true, how to do that?

Comment: @ShamnadPS I would suggest you [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) when you have something else to ask. This is answering the question you actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
    $group: {
        _id:1,
        valid:{
            $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$items.valid',true]},1,0]}
        }
        ,
        nonValid:{
              $sum: {$cond: {if:{$eq: ["$items.valid",false]},then:1,else:0}}
        },
             count:{$sum: 1},
    }
},
{
    $project: {_id:0}
}
)
```

You need to `group` the document with Id as 1 and take count with condition using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and suppress `_id`.